# In opencv python how to apply local daisy feature transform in an image

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, watermark, feature-detection, opencv3.0

Which is the function used to apply LDFT in an image using OpenCV.
I want to construct a feature space with LDFT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [`DAISY::compute(InputArray image, OutputArray descriptors)`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d9/d37/classcv_1_1xfeatures2d_1_1DAISY.html#a989b3fe67aadfebf4180ec85dc2cfc4d) which computes the DAISY descriptors for every pixel in the image. Unfortunately this isn't documented correctly yet but you have to look at [the source](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xfeatures2d/src/daisy.cpp).

Comment: I have compute daisy descriptors.Whether computing daisy descriptors and applying local daisy feature transform are same?

Comment: I assumed that was what you meant. Usually applying a feature transform means calculating the feature space which all is just a fancy way of saying that you compute feature descriptors. But what do you mean by "local" exactly?

Comment: local daisy feature transform is the new feature transform proposed in the paper "LDFT-Based Watermarking Resilient to Local
Desynchronization Attacks" by Huawei Tian, Yao Zhao in IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON CYBERNETICS, VOL. 43, NO. 6, DECEMBER 2013

Comment: OpenCV's DAISY features are an implementation of this paper E. Tola , V. Lepetit and P. Fua  "DAISY: An efficient dense descriptor applied to wide-baseline stereo". It is cited by the paper you mentioned so I guess they built on it. But I don't know it so you'd have to investigate further.

Comment: Which all features are extracted by using daisy transform?What does the values of daisy descriptors mean?